# Does a SurfaceTexture survive an activity pause/resume cycle?

Tags: android

Below is a little experiment I made where I attach a SurfaceTextureListener to a TextureView in the onResume() part of an activity.

- *on fresh start* : a surface texture is made available ("onSurfaceTextureAvailable")
- *on orientation change* : as I would expect, the surface texture is destroyed ("onSurfaceTextureDestroyed") and a surface texture is then made available ("onSurfaceTextureAvailable").

**Now here's what surprises me:**

- *on task switch then resume* : the surface  texture is not destroyed (no "onSurfaceTextureDestroyed") and a surface texture is not made available (no "onSurfaceTextureAvailable")

**Under these conditions, am I guaranteed that the old SurfaceTexture is stil valid? How can I make sure that I actually know when my SurfaceTexture is available? Why is it that an orientation change is different from a task switch and how should I know?**

---

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private final String TAG = "MainActivity";
    TextureView mTextureView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mTextureView = (TextureView) findViewById(R.id.textureView);
     }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mTextureView.setSurfaceTextureListener(new TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSurfaceTextureAvailable(SurfaceTexture surface, int width, int height) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onSurfaceTextureAvailable");
            }
            @Override
            public void onSurfaceTextureSizeChanged(SurfaceTexture surface, int width, int height) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onSurfaceTextureSizeChanged");
            }
            @Override
            public boolean onSurfaceTextureDestroyed(SurfaceTexture surface) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onSurfaceTextureDestroyed");
                return false;
            }
            @Override
            public void onSurfaceTextureUpdated(SurfaceTexture surface) {
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I´d say it is not an issue and it is not a "normal" or "expected to be" behaviour. It´s got a lot to do with the hardware of your device and how the system handles an overload in resource usages or harware changes.

May your device have a very flexible graphics accelerator, then your surfaces may survive an orientation change. See thatn when the device is titled, the video mode changes completelly and remember those times programming for desktop devices when all the DirectX surfaces (surfaces are video memory) should have to be recreated after a video mode change as from desktop windowed to full screen or viceversa.

Same thing happens when, maybe your application is a heavy resource usage game that´s using up all the video memory amount as for surfaces for textures or backbuffers, or so... If you switch to another application and this new one needs surface space, some or all of your video memory should be killed for this new screen to work.

And thus... You see?... It may happen that you don´t use up to the whole lot of the video memory or just you´ve got an badass device with the latest software that can handle both *light* or *soft* changes not destroying your resources.

The moral of my, otherwise useless, speech is that you have to handle the destroy for in case it is destroyed even when it is never happening in your device or you will have lots of exceptions trying to lock a canvas or rendering on null.